# Migrate_d2d: Excluding node import based on a date comparison

Tags: migrations

For a migrate_d2d project, D7 -> D7, I wish to exclude the importing of nodes whose date field is less than the current date. My only class overrides are for mapping custom fields. The migrate function is working as I expect. However, we don't need to import nodes whose dates have passed today's date.

The custom node field is not part of the core field data set, so the following:

```
public function prepareRow($row)
{
    $postDate = $node->field_job_start[und][0][value2];
    if ($postDate < time()) {
        return FALSE;
}
```

Will not work, as 'field_job_start' isn't accessible until prepare() by which time, apparently, a `return FALSE` doesn't cancel the row import.

What is the best way to exclude these rows?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in prepareRow. Whatever value is mapped to field_job_start, check its value there and return FALSE.

Comment: Thanks, but please re-read what I wrote.

Comment: Whatever value is eventually inserted into field_job_start, you'll need to get that value in prepareRow and check its value there. It won't work after prepareRow.